# Sphinx - Documenting Django models

Tags: django, django-models, python-sphinx

I'm using Sphinx in order to document a Django application I have.

When auto-generating documents I would like Sphinx to add the fields of each module within the documentation.

Sphinx totally skips these. In fact there is no trace of the fields whatsoever.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use

```
@param description
```

in the model's docstring, for each field you want to be documented by sphinx.

Or in alternative, you should take a look at this [snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2533/) that does what you want (minus the boring writing part)

[EDIT]

If you plan to use this snippet, in django>=1.6

```
obj._meta._fields()
```

has been removed please change it to

```
_meta.fields
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a snippet mentioned by @Samuele Mattiuzzo above, updated to support actual Django versions (tested on 1.11 LTS):

```
import inspect
from django.utils.html import strip_tags

def process_docstring(app, what, name, obj, options, lines):
    # This causes import errors if left outside the function
    from django.db import models

    # Only look at objects that inherit from Django's base model class
    if inspect.isclass(obj) and issubclass(obj, models.Model):
        # Grab the field list from the meta class
        fields = obj._meta.fields

        for field in fields:
            # Decode and strip any html out of the field's help text
            help_text = strip_tags(field.help_text)

            # Decode and capitalize the verbose name, for use if there isn't
            # any help text
            verbose_name = field.verbose_name

            if help_text:
                # Add the model field to the end of the docstring as a param
                # using the help text as the description
                lines.append(u':param %s: %s' % (field.attname, help_text))
            else:
                # Add the model field to the end of the docstring as a param
                # using the verbose name as the description
                lines.append(u':param %s: %s' % (field.attname, verbose_name))

            # Add the field's type to the docstring
            lines.append(u':type %s: %s' % (field.attname, type(field).__name__))

    # Return the extended docstring
    return lines


def setup(app):
    # Register the docstring processor with sphinx
    app.connect('autodoc-process-docstring', process_docstring)
```

Just add it to the end of your `conf.py` and model fields will be added automatically to documentation.

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to use this [snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2533/), in django 1.7+:

1. You had to setup your django project

   `django.setup()`
2. Use

   `obj._meta.get_fields()`

   instead of:

   `obj._meta._fields()`

Comment: Thank you for this! There's other SO questions that have helpful references on how to adjust the env to ensure `django.setup()` works, e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50879154/cant-generate-autodoc-using-sphinx-in-my-django-project

Answer (score 1):

What you easily could do is add a docstring below each field.
Sphinx will recognize this and render a description for each field.

```py
class Person(models.Model):
    """The model's docstring"""

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=23)
    """This is the first name pf the person"""

    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=23)
    "This is the last name pf the person"
    # even single-quoted strings work.
```

This is easier as the other approach and keeps the documentation where it should be: at the target.

Comment: in addition using `:undoc-members:` with `autoclass` works just fine for fields without docstring.

Comment: This is not DRY because in a real project you will have `verbose_name` and/or `help_text` attributes filled.